# C# Multithreading Context - the behavior of methods & event handlers from .NET and/or UWP -

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, uwp

I have some general questions about Multithreading while developing .NET/UWP apps. I will take as an example the UWP.

[Axiom 1] In UWP, we have the UI thread (where runs everything about UI elements: init, event raising, etc.) and the non-UI thread.

1. While architecturing a new library (in our case, an UWP library), OR while calling .NET methods, OR while a Non-UI-related event occurs (as an example, from a DeviceWatcher Update event), ***should we keep in mind*** that **we don't know** on which thread will it run ?

We want to modify an UI element in the DeviceWatcher's Update event handler. **Should we always be aware** that we don't know on which thread it runs? So we need to:

```
 private async void DeviceWatcher_Updated(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation deviceInfo)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            // ToDo
        });
    }
```

or in the case of having/creating a custom class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // ...
    public async Task ModifySomethingOnUIThread()
    {
       await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            // ToDo
        });
    }
}
```

In general, .NET documentation does not specify for each .NET entity (method, event) the default behavior. Specifically, on which thread will the first code run - without having Dispatcher.RunAsync()?

2. Also, from architecture point of view, **should we** manage thread-dependent cases **in our method** or **let the caller to be aware of** this aspect - possibly adding in description *You should run this method on the UI thread.* ? (because, again, we have pros and cons: it's easier to manage in your library(e.g. method), but on the other hand we should know nothing about UI). [Specifically, "who" is wrapping with Dispatcher.RunAsync() - the caller or the callee]

These are just some examples. But, as well, we can talk about thread X and Y.

Comment: "In nearly any Display technology, we have the UI thread (where runs everything about UI elements: init, event raising, etc.) and the non-UI threads." | The main thing about UI related stuff, is that you get it in the Event Queue of the UI thread. In Windows Forms you would invoke. In WPF/UWP, it is handing it off to the dispatcher.

Comment: Hi, It seems that you have questions about when to call `Dispatcher.RunAsync`. Yes, UWP application have UI threads and non-UI threads. In most cases, non-UI threads try to communicate with the UI thread (for example, we have opened a new thread to process the data, and after processing is complete, we need to call Dispatcher.RunAsync() when it is displayed on the TextBlock. ). More often, we can solve the problem by async/await.